# std::move vs. compiler optimization

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, move-semantics

For example:

```
void f(T&& t); // probably making a copy of t

void g() 
{
    T t;
    // do something with t
    f(std::move(t));
    // probably something else not using "t"
}
```

Is `void f(T const& t)` equivalent in this case because any good compiler will produce the same code? I'm interested in >= VC10 and >= GCC 4.6 if this matters.

**EDIT:**

Based on the answers, I'd like to elaborate the question a bit:

Comparing `rvalue-reference` and `pass-by-value` approaches, it's so easy to forgot to use `std::move` in `pass-by-value`. Can compiler still check that no more changes are made to the variable and eliminate an unnecessary copy?

`rvalue-reference` approach makes only optimized version "implicit", e.g. `f(T())`, and requires the user to explicitly specify other cases, like `f(std::move(t))` or to explicitly make a copy `f(T(t));` if the user isn't done with `t` instance. So, in this optimization-concerned light, is `rvalue-reference` approach considered good?

Comment: There are not many times you should be taking an argument by rvalue reference other than when implementing a move constructor. And almost always it should be overloading a function that takes by `const` lvalue reference.

Comment: You don't need std::move(T(t), just T(t) will be enough since it is explicit T is no longer used after this function

Comment: @AndyT You have a misunderstanding about taking an rvalue reference argument. That doesn't perform a move at all.

Comment: @Alon: yeah, corrected that immediately after posting :)

Comment: @sftrabbit: please elaborate. I believe I do understand that rvalue-reference doesn't perform a move but requires it in some cases (when a variable has a name)

Comment: @AndyT Are you talking about when you do `std::move(variable)`? Just to be clear, `std::move` doesn't move anything either. It just makes it moveable. But nothing is moved.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21605579/how-true-is-want-speed-pass-by-value

Comment: And also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33872026/copy-elision-for-pass-by-value-arguments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's definitely not the same. For once `T &&` can *only* bind to rvalues, while `T const &` can bind both to rvalues and to lvalues. Second, `T const &` does not permit any move optimizations. If you "probably want to make a copy of `t`", then `T &&` allows you to actually make a move-copy of `t`, which is potentially more efficient.

Example:

```
void foo(std::string const & s) { std::string local(s); /* ... */ }

int main()
{
    std::string a("hello");
    foo(a);
}
```

In this code, the string buffer containing `"hello"` must exist twice, once in the body of `main`, and another time in the body of `foo`. By contrast, if you used rvalue references and `std::move(a)`, the very same string buffer can be "moved around" and only needs to be allocated and populated one single time.

As @Alon points out, the right idiom is in fact [passing-by-value](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/):

```
void foo(std::string local) { /* same as above */ }

int main()
{
    std::string a("hello");
    foo(std::move(a));
}
```

Comment: @KerrekSB, Yeah, please do check the edited question... Also, your "for one" sentence sounds 'lawyery' and evasive; the rest sounds like the real answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends what f does with t, if it creates a copy of it, then I would even go at length of doing this:

```
void f(T t) // probably making a copy of t
{
    m_newT = std::move(t); // save it to a member or take the resources if it is a c'tor..
}

void g() 
{
    T t;
    // do something with t
    f(std::move(t));
    // probably something else not using "t"
}
```

Then you allow the move c'tors optimization to happen, you take 't' resources in any case, and if it was 'moved' to your function, then you even gain the non copy of moving it to the function, and if it was not moved then you probably had to have one copy

Now if at later on in the code you'd have:

```
f(T());
```

Then ta da, free move optimization without the f user even knowing..

Note that quote: "is void f(T const& t) equivalent in this case because any good compiler will produce the same code?"

It is not equivelent, it is LESS work, because only the "pointer" is transferred and no c'tors are called at all, neither move nor anything else

Comment: Why would you make a local copy, and *then* move it into another local copy?

Comment: @juanchopanza: You don't actually make a local copy, since move c'tor is called, when you HAVE to make a local copy(and then take its resources so it's one copy either way) and you can't use move

Comment: @juanchopanza: what if `f` is a constructor?

Comment: You make a copy because you are taking the argument by value.

Comment: @juanchopanza (That is the all essence of move c'tors :) ), the 'copy' you make does not allocate any new resources

Comment: You already have `t`. You have no need to move into `newT`. You can just use `t`.

Comment: @Alon The point is there's no reason to do that. `t` is a local variable, whether it was copied or moved from, it's still local to that function and you don't need to copy/move it into `newT`.

Comment: @sftrabbit: can't believe you guys got stuck on that.. I gave it as an example on how to save it to a member..

Answer (score 1):

Taking an `const` lvalue reference and taking an rvalue reference are two different things.

Similarities:

- Neither will cause an copy or move to take place because they are both references. A reference just references an object, it doesn't copy/move it in any way.

Differences:

- A `const` lvalue reference will bind to anything (lvalue or rvalue). An rvalue reference will only bind to non-`const` rvalues - much more limited.
- The parameter inside the function cannot be modified when it is a `const` lvalue reference. It can be modified when it's an rvalue reference (since it is non-`const`).

Let's look at some examples:

1. Taking `const` lvalue reference: `void f(const T& t);`

   1. Passing an lvalue:

      ```
      T t; f(t);
      ```

      Here, `t` is an lvalue expression because it's the name of the object. A `const` lvalue reference can bind to anything, so `t` will happily be passed by reference. Nothing is copied, nothing is moved.
   2. Passing an rvalue:

      ```
      f(T());
      ```

      Here, `T()` is an rvalue expression because it creates a temporary object. Again, a `const` lvalue reference can bind to anything, so this is okay. Nothing is copied, nothing is moved.

   In both of these cases, the `t` inside the function is a reference to the object passed in. It can't be modified by the reference is `const`.
2. Taking an rvalue reference: `void f(T&& t);

   1. Passing an lvalue:

      ```
      T t;
      f(t);
      ```

      This will give you a compiler error. An rvalue reference will not bind to an lvalue.
   2. Passing an rvalue:

      ```
      f(T());
      ```

      This will be fine because an rvalue reference can bind to an rvalue. The reference `t` inside the function will refer to the temporary object created by `T()`.

Now let's consider `std::move`. First things first: `std::move` doesn't actually move anything. The idea is that you give it an lvalue and it turns it into an rvalue. That's all it does. So now, if your `f` takes an rvalue reference, you could do:

```
T t;
f(std::move(t));
```

This works because, although `t` is an lvalue, `std::move(t)` is an rvalue. Now the rvalue reference can bind to it.

So why would you ever take an rvalue reference argument? In fact, you shouldn't need to do it very often, except for defining move constructors and assignment operators. Whenever you define a function that takes an rvalue reference, you almost certainly want to give a `const` lvalue reference overload. They should almost always come in pairs:

```
void f(const T&);
void f(T&&);
```

Why is this pair of functions useful? Well, the first will be called whenever you give it an lvalue (or a `const` rvalue) and the second will be called whenever you give it a modifiable rvalue. Receiving an rvalue usually means that you've been given a temporary object, which is great news because that means you can ravage its insides and perform optimizations based on the fact that you know it's not going to exist for much longer.

So having this pair of functions allows you to make an optimization when you know you're getting a temporary object.

There's a very common example of this pair of functions: the copy and move constructors. They are usually defined like so:

```
T::T(const T&); // Copy constructor
T::T(T&&); // Move constructor
```

So a move constructor is really just a copy constructor that is optimized for when receiving a temporary object.

Of course, the object being passed isn't *always* a temporary object. As we've shown above, you can use `std::move` to turn an lvalue into an rvalue. Then it *appears* to be a temporary object to the function. Using `std::move` basically says "I allow you to treat this object as a temporary object." Whether it actually gets moved from or not is irrelevant.

However, beyond writing copy constructors and move constructors, you'd better have a good reason for using this pair of functions. If you're writing a function that takes an object and will behave exactly the same with it regardless of whether its a temporary object or not, simply take that object by value! Consider:

```
void f(T t);

T t;
f(t);
f(T());
```

In the first call to `f`, we are passing an lvalue. That will be *copied* into the function. In the second call to `f`, we are passing an rvalue. That object will be *moved* into the function. See - we didn't even need to use rvalue references to cause the object to be moved efficiently. We just took it by value! Why? Because the *constructor* that is used to make the copy/move is chosen based on whether the expression is an lvalue or an rvalue. Just let the copy/move constructors do their job.

As to whether different argument types result in the same code - well that's a different question entirely. The compiler operates under the *as-if rule*. This simply means that as long as the program behaves as the standard dictates, the compiler can emit whatever code it likes. So the functions may emit the same code if they happen to do exactly the same thing. Or they may not. However, it's a bad sign if you're functions that take a const lvalue reference and an rvalue reference are doing the same thing.