# C++ pass to function implementation object as interface type

Tags: c++, interface

I have interface that looks like this :

```
class GameObject
{
public:
    virtual ObjType getType() = 0;
    virtual void setType(ObjType ot) = 0;

protected:
    ObjType objtype;


};
```

then i have class that implement this interface

```
class SpriteObject : public GameObject
{
    public:
        SpriteObject();
        virtual ~SpriteObject();        
        ObjType getType() { return objtype; }
        void setType(ObjType ot) { objtype = ot; }

    private:

};



class LayerObject : public GameObject
    {
        public:
            LayerObject ();
            virtual ~LayerObject ();        
            ObjType getType() { return objtype; }
            void setType(ObjType ot) { objtype = ot; }

        private:

    };
```

in the main class i have function which i try to pass the SpriteObject to 
That looks like this :

```
bool HelloWorld::NodeAction(GameObject* &pGameObj)
{
}
```

when i try to do :

```
SpriteObject *pSpriteObject = new SpriteObject();
NodeAction(pSpriteObject);
```

im getting this error:

```
error C2664: 'bool HelloWorld::NodeAction(GameObject *&)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'SpriteObject *' to 'GameObject *&'
```

In the end i want to have global function that can get different Objects that implement GameObject .

Comment: Why do you want `bool HelloWorld::NodeAction(GameObject* &pGameObj)` instead of `bool HelloWorld::NodeAction(GameObject* pGameObj)`

Comment: i will change the pGameObj in the function i dont need the pointer copy 
but if it is aproblem i can pass as pointer also , now as i try it it looks like it worked ... why i can't pass pointer reference?

Comment: Why do you hate the pointer copy? Have you read this [How true is “Want Speed? Pass by value”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21605579/4115625)

Comment: By the way, are you sure that your `getType` thing is not just reinventing the `dynamic_cast` or `typeid` wheel? Avoiding RTTI is not just about removing those two keywords; it concerns the application's entire class design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function:

```
bool HelloWorld::NodeAction(GameObject* &pGameObj)
```

expects a non-cv lvalue reference of `GameObject*`.

Because `pSpriteObject` is a lvalue of type `SpriteObject *`, there're no match function to call for it, it will try to use [implicit conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) to find an overload function by those conversion:

- Lvalue to rvalue conversion

  > A glvalue of any non-function, non-array type T can be implicitly converted to a prvalue of the same type. If T is a non-class type, this conversion also removes cv-qualifiers.
- Pointer conversions

  > A prvalue pointer to a (optionally cv-qualified) derived class type can be converted to a prvalue pointer to its (identically cv-qualified) base class.

Hence, this line

NodeAction(pSpriteObject);

expects a function with one of those prototypes:

```
bool HelloWorld::NodeAction(GameObject*)
bool HelloWorld::NodeAction(GameObject* const&)
bool HelloWorld::NodeAction(GameObject* &&)
```

All is acceptable but

```
bool HelloWorld::NodeAction(GameObject*)
```

should be preferred, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21605579/4115625). With primitive type, pass by value should be faster than pass-by-reference even if pre-C++11