# std::move or std::forward when assigning universal constructor to member variable in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, move-semantics, perfect-forwarding

Consider the following classes `foo1` and `foo2`

```
template <typename T>
struct foo1
{
    T t_;

    foo1(T&& t) :
        t_{ std::move(t) }
    {
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct foo2
{
    foo1<T> t_;

    foo2(T&& t) :
        t_{ std::forward<T>(t) }
    {
    }
};
```

Is it always the case that the constructor of `foo1` represents the correct way to initialise the member variable `T`? i.e. by using `std::move`.

Is it always the case that the constructor of `foo2` represents the correct way to initialise the member variable `foo1<T>` due to needing to forward to foo1's constructor? i.e. by using `std::forward`.

**Update**

The following example fails for `foo1` using `std::move`:

```
template <typename T>
foo1<T> make_foo1(T&& t)
{
    return{ std::forward<T>(t) };
}

struct bah {};

int main()
{
    bah b;

    make_foo1(b); // compiler error as std::move cannot be used on reference

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Which is a problem as I want T to be both a reference type and a value type.

Comment: I'll let someone who knows the reason behind it post a full answer, but if you're looking for a quick yes/no, I've always been told that your `foo2` example is correct.

Comment: These are not "universal" (forwarding) reference - You need a templated constructor if you want a forwarding reference.

Comment: There's no assignment here.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit  I have updated my wording, thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Neither of these examples use universal references (forwarding references, as they are now called).

Forwarding references are only formed in the presence of type deduction, but `T&&` in the constructors for `foo1` and `foo2` is not deduced, so it's just an rvalue reference.

Since both are rvalue references, you should use `std::move` on both.

If you want to use forwarding references, you should make the constructors have a deduced template argument:

```
template <typename T>
struct foo1
{
    T t_;

    template <typename U>
    foo1(U&& u) :
        t_{ std::forward<U>(u) }
    {
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct foo2
{
    foo1<T> t_;

    template <typename U>
    foo2(U&& u) :
        t_{ std::forward<U>(u) }
    {
    }
};
```

You should not use `std::move` in `foo1` in this case, as client code could pass an lvalue and have the object invalidated silently:

```
std::vector<int> v {0,1,2};
foo1<std::vector<int>> foo = v;
std::cout << v[2]; //yay, undefined behaviour
```

A simpler approach would be to take by value and unconditionally `std::move` into the storage:

```
template <typename T>
struct foo1
{
    T t_;

    foo1(T t) :
        t_{ std::move(t) }
    {
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct foo2
{
    foo1<T> t_;

    foo2(T t) :
        t_{ std::move(t) }
    {
    }
};
```

For the perfect forwarding version:

- Passed lvalue -> one copy
- Passed rvalue -> one move

For the pass by value and move version:

- Passed lvalue -> one copy, one move
- Passed rvalue -> two moves

Consider how performant this code needs to be and how much it'll need to be changed and maintained, and choose an option based on that.

Comment: _"You should not use std::move in foo1 in this case, it it would fail to compile if the constructor is passed a non-const lvalue."_ Why's that?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, does that mean I would also use `std::move` in this scenario: `template <class T> auto make_foo1(T&& t) { return foo1<T>{ std::move(t) }; }` because there is no type deduction?

Comment: @keith I'm not sure what you mean; `T` is deduced from the function argument in your `make_foo`. You should use `std::forward<T>(t)` in this case.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but technically, the pass-by-value and move version, for a temporary rvalue (something constructed on that line, e.g. result of a return-by-value function, direct constructor call, etc.; my nomenclature is weak, but I think this might be described as a `prvalue`?), [RVO can be used to construct directly into `t`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21605827/364696), right? So the r-value case for pass-by-value and move could, in case of RVO, be just one move too. Still slower on average (for three possible cases, adds an average of 0.66 moves), but it matches for one case.

Comment: If it is valid for `T` to be a reference type, then you should `forward`.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on how you deduce `T`.  For example:

```
template<class T>
foo1<T> make_foo1( T&& t ) {
  return std::forward<T>(t);
}
```

In this case, the `T` in `foo1<T>` is a forwarding reference, and your code won't compile.

```
std::vector<int> bob{1,2,3};
auto foo = make_foo1(bob);
```

the above code silently moved from `bob` into a `std::vector<int>&` within the constructor to `foo1<std::vector<int>&>`.

Doing the same with `foo2` would work.  You'd get a `foo2<std::vector<int>&>`, and it would hold a reference to `bob`.

When you write a template, you must consider what it means for the type `T` to be reference.  If your code doesn't support it being a reference, consider `static_assert` or SFINAE to block that case.

```
template <typename T>
struct foo1 {
  static_assert(!std::is_reference<T>{});
  T t_;

  foo1(T&& t) :
    t_{ std::move(t) }
  {
  }
};
```

Now this code generates a reasonable error message.

You might think the existing error message was ok, but it was only ok because we moved into a `T`.

```
template <typename T>
struct foo1 {
  static_assert(!std::is_reference<T>{});

  foo1(T&& t)
  {
    auto internal_t = std::move(t);
  }
};
```

here only the `static_assert` ensured that our `T&&` was actual an rvalue.

---

But enough with this theoretical list of problems.  You have a concrete one.

In the end this is probably want you want:

```
template <class T> // typename is too many letters
struct foo1 {
  static_assert(!std::is_reference<T>{});
  T t_;

  template<class U,
    class dU=std::decay_t<U>, // or remove ref and cv
    // SFINAE guard required for all reasonable 1-argument forwarding
    // reference constructors:
    std::enable_if_t<
      !std::is_same<dU, foo1>{} && // does not apply to `foo1` itself
      std::is_convertible<U, T> // fail early, instead of in body
    ,int> = 0
  >
  foo1(U&& u):
    t_(std::forward<U>(u))
  {}
  // explicitly default special member functions:
  foo1()=default;
  foo1(foo1 const&)=default;
  foo1(foo1 &&)=default;
  foo1& operator=(foo1 const&)=default;
  foo1& operator=(foo1 &&)=default;
};
```

or, the simpler case that is just as good in 99/100 cases:

```
template <class T>
struct foo1 {
  static_assert(!std::is_reference<T>{});
  T t_;

  foo1(T t) :
    t_{ std::move(t) }
  {}
  // default special member functions, just because I never ever
  // want to have to memorize the rules that makes them not exist
  // or exist based on what other code I have written:
  foo1()=default;
  foo1(foo1 const&)=default;
  foo1(foo1 &&)=default;
  foo1& operator=(foo1 const&)=default;
  foo1& operator=(foo1 &&)=default;
};
```

As a general rule, this simpler technique results in exactly 1 move more than the perfect forwarding technique, in exchange for a huge amount less code and complexity.  And it permits `{}` initialization of the `T t` argument to your constructor, which is nice.