# c++ string manipulation in setter

Tags: c++, string, setter

Can I manipulate string in setter? For example I want to set it length to 20. Is it that possible and is it the best practice? I get "Non const function is called on const object". Code tried:

```
void setName(const string &name) {
    if (name.size() > 20)
    {
        name.reserve(20);
    }
    Employee::name = name;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in your example `name` is a `const string` reference so you can only use `const` methods on it (basically meaning you can't modify `name`). The `reserve` is not a `const` method. The `const string& name` means that `name` is the **same** string as the caller supplied, the `const` means that you may not modify it.

What you could do however is to create a copy of `name` somehow. The most obvious way is maybe to create a copy inside the method, this means that you can keep the function signature (which may be a good thing IMHO):

```
void setName(const string &name) {
    string tname = name;
    if (tname.size() > 20)
    {
        tname.reserve(20);
    }
    Employee::name = tname;
}
```

Another way you could do it is to pass `name` by value which means that the argument will be a copy of what was supplied by the caller (one could argue that one shouldn't alter the signature of the method to reflect the implementation, but that's a matter of opinion):

```
void setName(string name) { // note no ampersand
```

What you **can't**/**shouldn't** do is to only remove the `const` because that would mean that the argument is the **same** string as the caller supplied. It will fail to compile if the caller don't supply a mutable name and if supplied a mutable name the callers copy would change as well (since it's the same).

Comment: Of course, I completely misread the sentence or was having a blackout! Sorry, I'm going to delete my comment :)

Comment: You should `= std::move(tname)` instead of `= tname` to avoid a needless copy :)  (same if you take the param by copy)

Comment: @tuple_cat My intention was not to make this an optimal solution. The better solution might be to work on `Employee::name` directly and therefore avoiding a needless copy altogether (`move` could still do some needless copying).

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are addressing the problem in the wrong way.
The code posted calls [reserve](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/reserve) when the size of the string passed is higher then 20, but that is a non-binding request to shrink the string (which is const, BTW).

If you want to limit that string member of your class to a particular size while passing a const reference in a setter, all you have to do is copying into it only a substring of the passed string.

Comment: The `reserve()` call will do nothing here, because `capacity()` must be at least `size()`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Yes, that's actually what I was trying to express with my bad phrasing.

Comment: Now that I'm thinking about it, perhaps my statement is not entirely true either. The string's size may be 30, its capacity 1000. Then `reserve(20)` *may* shrink the capacity to 30.

Comment: @ChristianHackl looking at the reference that's the expected behavior, including the _may_...

Answer (score 1):

> I get "Non const function is called on const object"

Of course. That's the **whole point** of `const` in the first place!

> ```
> if (name.size() > 20)
> {
>     name.reserve(20);
> }
> ```

This does not make sense at all. It literally says: *"If the string has more than 20 characters, then make sure that it can internally hold at least 20 characters"*.

Now, the call *may* also have the effect that the string's internal capacity shrinks to whatever size greater than 20 it represents to the outside world. For example, if your string has size 30 and its current capacity is 1000, then `reserve(20)` *may* shrink the capacity to 30.

However, this is a low-level memory-management concern a beginner typically doesn't or shouldn't care about. If, what I believe, your intention is merely to **cut** the string, then you need `resize`.

I would solve your problem like this, plain and simple:

```
void setName(std::string const& name)
{
    this->name = name;
    if (this->name.size() > 20)
    {
        this->name.resize(20);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mutate `const` references: this means that you will not be able to call `std::string::reserve` as it's not `const`-qualified.

Consider taking `name` by value:

```
void setName(string name) 
 {
    if (name.size() > 20)
    {
        name.reserve(20);
    }

    Employee::name = name;
}
```

In this case, a copy of the string passed to `setName` will be made, which can be mutated leaving the original unchanged.

Comment: @TeodorKolev: if you need to mutate the argument before setting it, you have to get rid of the `const`.

Comment: const helps out caller because he can pass a string literal.

Comment: I disagree with this approach, because taking the string by value because you need an internal copy means that you have compromised the interface of the function for its implementation.

Comment: @Christian Hackl: setters in C++11 should take by value and move anyway. Sink interfaces taking by value are idiomatic

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: That looked like the new recommendation for a while when C++11 was new, but it's no longer the case. See https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/10/quick-q-why-is-want-speed-pass-by-value-not-recommended-stackoverflow or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21605579/how-true-is-want-speed-pass-by-value

Comment: @ChristianHackl: I know about the drawbacks of the idiom. [I think that this is a great article on the subject](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2014/08/21/c-sink-parameter-passing/). My point is that for `std::string`, when `noexcept` is not involved, and when the string is being retained... pass-by-value + move is superior to pass by `const&`. Regardless, changing the interface of `setName` shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean: you can pass a string literal even when passing `std::string` by value.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: I know the advantages of the idiom :) But all the arguments in favour of pass-by-value seem to be implementation-centric or optimisation-related. The latter is often not a problem to begin with, and the former disregards the potential for changes. For example, the implementation may evolve into a more complex mechanism where nothing is written to another `std::string` object at all. IOW, it may be a "sink" at the moment, but not in the future.