# boost::graph function with edge iterator passed by value and graph passed by reference

Tags: c++, boost, graph

The following code appears in boost graph library manual available [here](https://markqiu.files.wordpress.com/2009/12/boost-graph-library.pdf).

[image]

I have no problem understanding what the code does. My questions are:

(1)Why is the graph object passed as a constant reference. `const Graph& g` ?

(2)Why is the edge descriptor not passed similarly, but simply by value?

As I understand, the answer to (1) is that it imposes a constraint to ensure that the function `is_self_loop()` does not modify the object `g` and also that no copy is made of `g` within the function.

On the other hand, a copy is indeed made within the function of the `edge_descriptor`.

Is there any reason to accord these two different reasonings for the two passed objects? The function does not seem to alter `e` either, so why not pass it as a `const` and also to prevent a local copy, why not also pass it as a reference? Does this have to do with the sizes of `g` and `e`? That is, copying `e` is not a costly operation? If yes, how can the user figure out which object is "easy" to copy and which object is expensive to copy?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270408/is-it-better-in-c-to-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-constant-reference

Comment: The descriptors are _descriptors_: they are by definition efficient to copy. Compilers have a much easier time optimizing values than references (aliasing is a pain), see the comments at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21605579/how-true-is-want-speed-pass-by-value/21607854