# Copy elision for pass-by-value arguments

Tags: c++, pass-by-value, copy-elision

Given

```
struct Range{
    Range(double from, double to) : from(from), to(to) {}
    double from;
    double to;
};

struct Box{
    Box(Range x, Range y) : x(x), y(y) {}
    Range x;
    Range y;
};
```

suppose we run `Box box(Range(0.0,1.0),Range(0.0,2.0))`.

Could a modern compiler with optimizations enabled avoid copying `Range` objects altogether during this construction? (i.e. construct the `Range` objects inside `box` to begin with?)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are actually two copies being performed on each `Range` object passed to the constructor. The first happens when copying the temporary `Range` object into the function parameter. This can be elided as per the reference given in 101010's answer. There are [specific circumstances](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) in which copy elision can be performed.

The second copy happens when copying the function parameter into the member (as specified in the constructor initialization list). This cannot be elided, and this is why you still see a single copy being made for each parameter in YSC's answer.

When the copy constructor has side-effects (such as the prints in YSC's answer), copy elision can still be performed for the first copy, but the second copy must remain.

However, the compiler is always free to make changes if they do not alter the observed behavior of the program (this is known as the "as-if" rule). This means that if the copy constructor has no side effects and removing the constructor call will not change the result, the compiler is free to remove even the second copy.

You can see this by analyzing the generated assembly. In [this example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%2C%22intel%22%3Atrue%2C%22colouriseAsm%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22sourcez%22%3A%22MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4QHsDOAXATggQwFsA%2BAKDJ1xgmyQCUCwBzBAbzKS4adYAo46GACMoyAGa50RADRJBIsUmzoAlEgBcSSdL46iquSr4r1bAL6duC0RKlEA3Fa42lKp%2BaeU8NOgCF0AA8ObiQAwL5GFmRAuSjWJABPdS0IwMMkvmSkC2ceaKRAp1D45ESPL3A6IgJwPlUyEKQASFdkAhlhGQgZOGKWnDgNDQhwJBISJAJxyeEZpAh5vqQAehX8AjgkcAAHGDoVJB38ADcEMAP0dCQasESkdB3sECIQAC8CZ%2FQwTCtm8KQwiCkV4CD4HWEhlKfB6cFUqn6XEGwwgQjoKBQgKCADpAtj9B4yEAAA%3D%3D%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22g447%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-std%3Dc%2B%2B0x%20-O3%22%7D%5D%7D), the compiler optimizes out not only the copies, but even the construction of the `Box` object itself:

```
Box box(Range(a,b),Range(c,d));
std::cout << box.x.from;
```

Generates identical assembly as:

```
std::cout << a;
```

Comment: Maybe this could be improved if you cited more clearly that there are two things at play here (1) Copy Elision, which allows eliding copies no matter how the copy constructor/destructor are implemented, is a C++ specific rule and (2) the As If rule, which allows eliding any code that does not change the behavior, is a generic optimizer rule. The other answers failed at (2) because they started instrumenting the copy constructor/destructor calls to witness the copies which in turn inhibited the "As If" rule and thus had the optimizers retain the copy behavior.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I've edited to hopefully make the distinction clearer.

Comment: "When the copy constructor has side-effects (such as the prints in YSC's answer), copy elision can still be performed for the first copy, but the second copy must remain." Do you have a source for this? I'd be interested to learn more about it.

Comment: @JordanMelo If you're asking why the first copy can be elided, it's because the standard allows it in its rules for [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), which is applicable even if the constructor has side effects. The relevant rule here is eliding a copy from a temporary. If you're asking why the second must remain, it's because it doesn't fall into the allowed applications for copy elision, and due to its having side-effects it can't be removed by the [as-if rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if).

Comment: Why doesn't the second case fall into the allowed applications for copy elision? Is it because it's not a copy from a temporary?

Comment: @JordanMelo Correct. The constructor parameters `from` and `to` are named variables and therefore not temporaries.

Comment: @MatthieuM but copy elision is the one case where the compiler does **not** have to maintain side-effects that would be mandatory everywhere else under the _as-if_ rule and is allowed to discard them. detecting whether elision is occurring based on the presence or absence of instrumented `cout`s is a tried-and-tested technique. the compiler is not required to keep those `cout`s around.

Comment: Does this answer change with C++17?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider In C++17, the copy elision for the first copy becomes mandatory rather than optional.

Comment: @interjay, do you know the name of the technique for "the copy elision for the first copy becomes mandatory rather than optional."? Thanks

Comment: And also, is the first copy elision guaranteed?

Answer (score 6):

Yes it can, In particular this kind of copy elision context falls under the copy elision criterion specified in *12.8/p31.3 Copying and moving class objects [class.copy]* of the standard:

> (31.3) -- when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference
>   (12.2) would be copied/moved to a class object with the same type
>   (ignoring cv-qualification), the copy/move operation can be omitted by
>   constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the
>   omitted copy/move.

Any descent compiler apply copy elision in this particular context. However, in the OP example two copies taking place.

1. The temporary objects passed in the constructor (That can be elide per standard as mentioned above).
2. The copies in the `Box` constructor's initializer list (That can't be elided).

You can see it in this [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4d678c4cdb1465a6) where the copy constructor is evoked only 2 times.

Have also in mind that, because the standard allows in a particular context copy elision optimization, doesn't mean that a compiler vendor is obligated to do it. Copy elision is the only allowed form of optimization that can change the observable side-effects. Consequently, due to the fact that some compilers do not perform copy elision in every situation where it is allowed (e.g., in debug mode), **programs that rely on the side-effects of copy/move constructors and destructors are not portable.**

Comment: I can't get it to happen. An example would go a long way towards convincing me.

Comment: The down-voters would be so kind to explain the reason of their down-vote? If there's really any...?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the downvoters probably came from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33873047/will-any-compiler-actually-ever-elide-these-copies) which links to your answer. I suppose they downvoted because your answer was partly incorrect before you edited (the question asks if the copies can be completely elided, to which to answer should be no).

Comment: @101010, is the "12.8/p31.3" copy elision mandatory?

Comment: @dragonxlwang https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision#:~:text=C%2B%2B17)-,Non%2Dmandatory%20elision%20of%20copy%2Fmove%20(since%20C%2B%2B,destructor%20have%20observable%20side%2Deffects.] check mandatory.

Comment: just to be clear: is this the part "in the initialization of an object, when the initializer expression is a prvalue of the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the variable type:", so it has become guaranteed since c++17

Comment: @dragonxlwang yeap, for the cases that is mandatory.

Answer (score 5):

It should, but [I fail to make it work (live example)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0db5834511e9df68). The compiler may detect the side-effect of the constructors and decide not to go with copy elision.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Range{
    Range(double from, double to) : from(from), to(to) { std::cout << "Range(double,double)" << std::endl; }
    Range(const Range& other) : from(other.from), to(other.to) { std::cout << "Range(const Range&)" << std::endl; }
    double from;
    double to;
};

struct Box{
    Box(Range x, Range y) : x(x), y(y) { std::cout << "Box(Range,Range)" << std::endl; }
    Box(const Box& other) : x(other.x), y(other.y) { std::cout << "Box(const Box&)" << std::endl; }
    Range x;
    Range y;
};


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    (void) argv;
    const Box box(Range(argc, 1.0), Range(0.0, 2.0));
    std::cout << box.x.from << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compile & run:

```
clang++ -std=c++14 -O3 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
```

Output:

```
Range(double,double)
Range(double,double)
Range(const Range&)
Range(const Range&)
Box(Range,Range)
1
```

Comment: But you are not printing from a copy constructor.

Comment: This does elide the two copy constructors going into the by-value constructor, it just doesn't elide the copy from the parameters into the `x` and `y` members. A common pattern is to take by-value then `std::move` into the data members.

Comment: @YSC Copy elision doesn't care about side effects. That is the whole point.

Comment: anyway, if you use `const Range &`  you're sure that there's no copy. I wouldn't rely on those optimization unless it's not my code and I can't rework it

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it can, doesn't mean it most certainly will. See it in this [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/725ac4828594dba2), it's obvious you are creating two copies. Hint, the output contains twice :

> copy made
>
> copy made

Comment: I don't think that's a fair test. The compiler **must** follow the as-if rule and emit code that calls the `cout`s you put in the code. So you have introduced a condition that prevents the copies from being elided.

Comment: @EvanTeran not true. copy elision is the one case where the compiler does **not** have to maintain side-effects that would be mandatory everywhere else under the _as-if_ rule and is allowed to discard them.

Comment: @underscore_d, interesting, thanks for the correction.