# Why should arguments be passed by value when used to initialize another object?

Tags: c++, c++11

When passing objects to functions there is the choice to pass arguments either by value or by `const&`. Especially when the object is possibly expensive to create and it is internally mutated or used to initialize another object the recommendation is to pass the object by value. For example:

```
class Foo {
    std::vector<std::string> d_strings;
public:
    Foo(std::vector<std::string> strings): d_strings(std::move(strings)) {}
    // ...
};
```

The conventional approach would be to declare the `strings` parameter as `std::vector<std::string> const&` and copy the argument. The value argument to the constructor above also needs to be copied!

Why is it preferable to pass by value rather than pass by `const&`?

Comment: It's perhaps a somewhat bold claim that passing by value is "the recommendation." I'd say it's definitely good advice for leaf code, since it's easy to teach, avoids complexity and users don't need to spell awkward punctuators like `&&`. However in generic library code it would seem more appropriate to have two overloads (`const string&` and `string&&`) so as not to force a mandatory copy/move (cheap as that may be).

Comment: @KerrekSB: creating one function is generally less error-prone than creating two functions. I do agree that a quality implementation may want to create both overloads although the `const&` version really just avoids a move when the copy actually needs to be done.

Comment: Another important determinant in the decision is whether you know the concrete parameter type, or whether you have generic code. In the former case you can be more confident about the cost of the extra move. For me, the distinction is not so much QoI but rather the level of generality and reuse of the code. The less I know about my users, the less I'll want to constrain them.

Comment: `move` is not necessary cheap: moving `std::array<T, 1024>` will do a copy anyway, so pass it by const reference.

Answer (score 4):

When passing the `strings` argument by `const&` there is a guaranteed copy: there is no other way to get hold a, well, copy of the argument other than copying it. The question becomes: how is that different when passing by value?

When the argument is passed by value the `strings` object is clearly used nowhere else and its content can be moved. Move construction of expansive to copy objects may still be comparatively cheap. For example, in the case of the `std::vector<std::string>` the move is just copying a few pointers to the new object and setting a few pointers to indicate to the original object that it shouldn't release anything.

There is still the need to create the argument, though. However, the creation of the argument may be elided without creating a new object. For example

```
Foo f(std::vector<std::string>{ "one", "two", "three" });
```

will create a vector with three strings and construction of the argument to the `Foo` construct is most likely elided. In the worst case, the argument is constructed by moving the temporary vector, avoiding a copy, too.

There are, of course, cases where a copy still needs to be created. For example, in the case

```
std::vector<std::string> v{ "one", "two", "three" };
Foo                      f(v);
```

The argument is created by a copy. The ready made copy is then moved to the member. In this case pass by `const&` would have been better because only a copy construction would have been needed rather than a copy construction (to create the argument) followed by a move construction (to create the member) being done.

That is, passing by value enables possibly eliding a copy entirely and just having a move. In the worst case, when the argument needs to be copied anyway, an additional move needs to be performed. Since the move is generally assumed to be a cheap operation the expectation is that overall pass by value for objects which need to be transferred results in better performance.

Comment: Have you seen Herbs talk about this at cppcon2014? What is your opinion on it?Personally I'd give a much more restricted general advice: "Only use pass by value, if you have to copy construct (not assign) the object inside anyway (and of course small/builtin types)".

Answer (score 4):

The statement

> Arguments should be passed by value when used to initialize another object

Is true, starting with C++11, thanks to the introduction of move semantic.
It could be generalized to:

> When a function needs a copy of one of its arguments, pass it by value.

This is actually well detailed in the "[Want Speed? Pass by Value.](https://web.archive.org/web/20140205194657/http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/)" article.

The outline is that, since your function will need a copy of the argument anyway, it is better to have this copy handled at the call-site instead of inside the called function. This is because, if the object that the function needs a copy is an Rvalue, it is only known at call site, thus enabling move optimization: the calling context is well aware that the object is expiring, and thus can move-it into the copy that the function requires. Now, if the copy was to be made inside the function itself, the notion that the source object (in the calling context) was an Rvalue would not be forwarded up to the actual place of the copy, loosing the opportunity for a move.

Comment: What if my class contains a data member of type `std::array<int, 100000>` that is to be initialized with the value of an existing object of this type? That's definitely "needing a copy of one of its arguments".